# How To Submit A Project at packalyst

Tags: laravel, packagist

How To Submit A Project at packalyst? not packagist

I cannot find any page I can submit.

Comment: Maybe you can submit a package after you log in the website.

Comment: Click  [paCkalyst](http://packalyst.com/contact) to get in touch :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It just pulls package names from Packagist that have a "laravel" tag. So submit your package to Packagist with the "laravel" tag, and it will then end up on Packagist.

Comment: how packalyst update a package? if package is updated on packagist then how it will be updated?

Comment: @Laurence how i submit my package on packalyst.com?

Comment: @FarshidRezaei - just crate an account there and there is a "submit" optoin

Comment: @Laurence sorry for reopening. But my package have `laravel` tag. Just updated composer.json to require needed `illuminate/..` packages. I created account on Packalyst but there is no submit button. What else I can do? My package is here: https://packagist.org/packages/arxeiss/passwordrule
Thank you